# Some questions on Trace (operators) on the boundary in the context of PDEs

Tags: finite-element, differential-equations

Background: The solution space of original problem (which requires a fine enough mesh to resolve the microstructure) can be split into a macroscale solution space and microscale solution space. This can be based on variational Multiscale Method (VMM) proposed by Hughes in 1998. By doing this, we can derive a multiscale formulation for the original heterogeneous problem. The final goal of most (multiscale) homogenisation based methods is to gain a smooth solution at the macroscale, but it also contains some information from the sub-scale. We can consider such a original problem a simple elasticity or Poisson's equation, which is bilinear form.

When I was reading a mechanics paper on two scale adaptive FE analysis for application in multicsale setting, I came across a sentence that the continuous space (i.e. the macroscale space) is the space of all fucnctions inside each RVE, that can reproduce the ***trace of functions*** in original solution space on the boundary of RVE's. 
So my question is what ***trace of functions*** means in PDEs. To try solving this myself, I did some online Google search and came out a Wiki link explaining trace operator  [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator), where an application into Poisson's equation is discussed.

Due to incomplete knowledge on functional analysis and measure theory, I cannot quite understand what the Wiki page is trying to describe? I attached a snapshot with my doubts highlighted in red. How to understand them? Also, you can elaborate exposition on trace of functions on boundary.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator]

Comment: The below may be a relevant and useful link to help my understanding. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88370/two-basic-questions-on-pdes-trace-operator-and-sobolev-space

Answer (score 6):

I think the quote from Wikipedia is misleading (and I should put that on my list of things to fix :-) ). You can think of the trace of a function $u: \Omega \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ that lives on a domain $\Omega$ as that function $g: \partial\Omega \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ that lives on the *boundary* of $\Omega$ and so that $u(\mathbf x)=g(\mathbf x)$ for all points $\mathbf x$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. In other words, it is the *restriction* of $u$ to the boundary.

Things are a bit more complicated than that because $u$ may be discontinuous at individual locations, and then it's not quite obvious how one would define $g$, but fundamentally the description above is what you should think of when you think of the trace.

Comment: FYI, I've "fixed" the intuitive description on wikipedia.